# Customize a swipe plugin with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to customize a swipe plugin with jQuery like the following:
[image]

My code structure is:

HTML

```
<div class="benefit-container">
  <div class="benefit-title-container">
    <div class="benefit-title">Why use Citrix Service Providers to Help Solve Your Business Problems?</div>
  </div>
  <div class="benefit-scroll-container">
    <div id="benefit-support" class="benefit-sub-title">Support</div>
    <div id="benefit-access" class="benefit-sub-title">Access</div>
    <div id="benefit-service" class="benefit-sub-title">Service</div>
    <div id="benefit-business-model" class="benefit-sub-title">Business Model</div>
    <div id="benefit-choice" class="benefit-sub-title">Choice</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.benefit-scroll-container{
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 36px;
    overflow-x: visible;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #cfd1d3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cfd1d3;
    line-height: 44px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

My thinking is: when touch move the plugin, I will change the position of benefit-scroll-container.

When I set the "benefit-scroll-container" class with the following and swipe left. I found some part lost as the following picture shown.

```
div.benefit-scroll-container{
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```

[image]

If I set the "benefit-scroll-container" class with the following.

```
div.benefit-scroll-container{
            overflow-x: visible;
        }
```

Then I swipe left, found the whole page will be swiped left and some of plugin lose the border like the follow picture shown.

[image]

**How can I solve this problem**?

Answer (score 0):

Give a certain width to div.benefit-scroll-container and then provide scroll property like this:

```
div.benefit-scroll-container {
        width: 1000px; //or 100% as per your use
        overflow-x: scroll;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to use scroll. just want change the div's position, is it possible?

Comment: @ZhiyuanSun Then set position:absolute, left: 0px, right:0px; and top according to where you want to place it.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my thinking. I want to customize a swipe plugin with horizontal slide.